# Is it possible to create a html table that flows column or row and wraps accordingly purely in CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm wondering if the following is possible without Javascript.
Let's say I have the following table (which wraps items to the next line going left to the right).

```
01  02  03  04
05  06  07  08
09  10  11  12
```

And I want to be able to toggle to column (going from up to down then wrap to the next column)

```
01  05  09
02  06  10
03  07  11
04  08  12
```

Ideally I'd want to be able to specify in a declarative manner like where I can specify the number of elements where it should wrap like (row-4 or column-4)

```
<div class="myContainer column-4">
    <div>01</div>
    <div>02</div>
    <div>03</div>
    <div>04</div>
    <div>05</div>
    <div>06</div>
    <div>07</div>
     ...
</div>
```

and if I want to switch (I'd simply update the css)

```
<div class="myContainer row-4">
    <div>01</div>
    <div>02</div>
    <div>03</div>
    <div>04</div>
    <div>05</div>
    <div>06</div>
    <div>07</div>
     ...
</div>
```

I've tried playing around with flex box because it has flex direction but I can't seem to wrap consistently based on whatever the elements are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alternate between `float` and css columns. I've made a JS Fiddle to demonstrate:

https://jsfiddle.net/p46vghrg/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flexbox` for that.

Check this example:

```css
table {
  display: flex;
}
table tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use columns with media queries, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/46/

```
.myContainer {
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .myContainer {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's fairly easy to build something that *looks* like a table but actually isn't a table.

```css
body { background: #eee; padding: 20px; margin:0; }

.faketabl { 
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;}

.row { display: block; clear: both;}
.row.header { 
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block; }

.col, .row.header > div  { 
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block; 
    background: #ffd;
    border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
    margin:0;
    padding: 2px 0;
    width: calc((100% / 6) - 2px); }
.col:nth-of-type(odd):not(nth-of-type(1)) {
   border-left: none; }
.col > div { border-bottom: 1px solid #2d2d2d; }
.col >div:last-of-type { border-bottom: none; }

.row.header > div { 
     border-bottom: none;
     background: #ff3;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; }
```

```html
<div class="faketabl">
  <div class="row header">
    <div>Title</div><div>Title</div><div>Title</div><div>Title</div><div>Title</div><div>Title</div>
   </div>
    
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div>01</div>
    <div>02</div>
    <div>03</div>
    <div>04</div>
    <div>05</div>
    <div>06</div>
    <div>07</div>
</div><div class="col">
    <div>01</div>
    <div>02</div>
    <div>03</div>
    <div>04</div>
    <div>05</div>
    <div>06</div>
    <div>07</div>
</div><div class="col">
    <div>01</div>
    <div>02</div>
    <div>03</div>
    <div>04</div>
    <div>05</div>
    <div>06</div>
    <div>07</div>
</div><div class="col">
    <div>01</div>
    <div>02</div>
    <div>03</div>
    <div>04</div>
    <div>05</div>
    <div>06</div>
    <div>07</div>
</div><div class="col">
    <div>01</div>
    <div>02</div>
    <div>03</div>
    <div>04</div>
    <div>05</div>
    <div>06</div>
    <div>07</div>
</div><div class="col">
    <div>01</div>
    <div>02</div>
    <div>03</div>
    <div>04</div>
    <div>05</div>
    <div>06</div>
    <div>07</div>
</div>
</div>

  <div class="row header">
    <div>Title</div><div>Title</div><div>Title</div>
   </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div>01</div>
    <div>02</div>
    <div>03</div>
    <div>04</div>
    <div>05</div>
    <div>06</div>
    <div>07</div>
</div><div class="col">
    <div>01</div>
    <div>02</div>
    <div>03</div>
    <div>04</div>
    <div>05</div>
    <div>06</div>
    <div>07</div>
</div><div class="col">
    <div>01</div>
    <div>02</div>
    <div>03</div>
    <div>04</div>
    <div>05</div>
    <div>06</div>
    <div>07</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you asked:
use `column-4` and `row-4` for your desired results

```css
.myContainer {
  width: 200px;
}
.myContainer div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column-4 div {
  float: left;
}
.row-4 {
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer column-4">
  <div>01</div>
  <div>02</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>06</div>
  <div>08</div>
  <div>09</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
```

Here is what you need:
use column-4 and row-4 for your desired results